# Unable to set Forms authentication to 'Enabled' for a web application under website in IIS through powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-7

I am trying to enable the forms authentication for a web application under the website in IIS. Following is the code I used for the same.

Code:

```
Write-Host "Setting App Form AuthMode for $($IISApp) to True"

Set-WebConfiguration -filter "system.web/authentication" -pspath
$IISApp -value @{mode='forms'}
```

Output:

```
Setting App Form AuthMode for IIS:\Sites\MySite\MyApp to True
```

Whatever I try I couldn't get the forms mode enable for the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.web/authentication" -name "mode" -value "Forms"
```